# ASP.NET Core: Problems loading dependencies of Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core-mvc

**The problem:**

I've been trying to resolve some issues with my dependencies of Javascript such as jQuery and bootstrap for my project.

However, at this moment, none of these are working properly.

**Diagnosis:**

All started with jQuery not being loaded working locally and I detected that it was because of the order of these componentes: bootstrap was being called before jQuery inside the _Layout file.

For this, I made the following changes to my _Layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html" charset="utf-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Plataforma Fantasy Park</title>

    <environment names="Development">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        <script src="~/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap-lumen.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/nestednavbar.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
    </environment>

    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~js/jquery-3.2.1.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-K+ctZQ+LL8q6tP7I94W+qzQsfRV2a+AfHIi9k8z8l9ggpc8X+Ytst4yBo/hH+8Fk">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="/css/bootstrap-sand.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>





    @RenderSection("css", required: false)
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2017 - Plataforma Fantasy Park</p>
        </footer>
    </div>




    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

With this the error of 404: resource not found was over. However now the components are not working: Navbars, modals, and such.

This is an example of a View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Application.Models.Store>
@using Application.Models
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
@Html.Partial("_NavBar")

@section scripts{

<script src="~/js/store-index.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/jquery-3.2.1.js">

    var global = this;
    var wasclicked = 0;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        document.getElementById("modalbutton").onclick = function () {
            global.wasclicked = 1;
        };

        $('#modal-action-store').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            global.wasclicked = 0;
        });

        $('#modal-action-store').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            if (global.wasclicked == 1) {
                var items = "<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Distrito --
</option>";
                $('#DistrictID').html(items);
            }
            $('#DepartmentID').change(function () {
                var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Stores/GetDistrict";
                var ddlsource = "#DepartmentID";
                $.getJSON(url, { DepartmentID: $(ddlsource).val() }, 
function (data) {
                    var items = '';
                    $("#DistrictID").empty();
                    $.each(data, function (i, district) {
                        items += "<option value='" + district.value + "'>" + district.text + "</option>";
                    });
                    $('#DistrictID').html(items);
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>

}

<h2>Tiendas</h2>

<div class="btn-group" id="modalbutton">
    <a id="createEditStoreModal" data-toggle="modal" asp-action="Create" data-target="#modal-action-store"
        class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>  Nueva Tienda
        </a>
</div>
<p></p>
<table id="stores" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Tienda
            </th>
            <th>
                Dirección
            </th>
            <th>
                Área
            </th>
            <th>
                Distrito
            </th>
            <th>
                Cadena
            </th>
            <th>Editar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StoreName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StoreAddress)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StoreArea)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Districts.DistrictName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StoreChains.ChainName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-group" id="modalbuttonedit">
                        <a id="editStoreModal" data-toggle="modal" asp-action="Create"
                            data-target="#modal-action-store" asp-route-id="@item.StoreID" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>}
    </tbody>
</table>

@Html.Partial("_Modal", new BootstrapModel
{
    ID = "modal-action-store",
    AreaLabeledId = "modal-action-store-label",
    Size = ModalSize.Medium
})
```

**Update:**

In this View, if I take out this reference `src="~/js/jquery-3.2.1.js"` and leave it like this:

```
@section scripts{

<script src="~/js/store-index.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

I get the error on the line for store-index.js:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

This is the code for the Navbar called:

```
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Menu</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">Plataforma Fantasy Park</a>
    </div>
    {...}
</div>
</nav>
```

I'm hoping to find some help and what might be wrong for these components to stop working. What else can I check besides the _Layout?

**Update:**

Continuing with the validations this is the result of the Network Tab:

[image]

Comment: You have a reference to jquery twice, once in your '_layout' and once in your view. Use only one and put it in the layout. Also, I cannot see a boostrap.css or boostrap.min.css file. You have one for datatables, one for 'lumen' (not sure what that is), but not the primary bootstrap css file (i.e. http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css)... looks like you have two bootstrap.js references too (once in you layout and once near your navbar - again, use only one).

Comment: @CalC Thanks for the response! When I take out the reference inside the view for jQuery I get an error in the line that references `store-index.js` saying: Failed to load resource: error 404. :(

Comment: Is the jQuery in your layout being loaded? Check the network tab in your browser dev tools.

Comment: OH, this might be it since it appears is being loaded from disk cache. Actually, most of the files are being loaded from cache. https://i.imgur.com/vJ6rEaq.png - but.. independent from the source, it is loaded into the project, however that problem appears

Comment: @CalC Navbar fixed :)

Comment: Hmm. Do you know what resource is not being loaded (producing the 404)? A screenshot of that might help too.

Comment: That error message is tricky. I mean, it is not that the file does not exist (it's there!) it's just that when the system finds this conflict of files (multiple references in diferent places for the same file) it does not acknowledge the rest of the files and the error message appear where the conflict starts. I fixed the double reference that was inside the navbar file and it seems it's working now.

Comment: @CalC No error messages about files not being loaded, however, the jquery scripts inside the view are not executing. I put breakpoints between lines but it's not stopping not even when reloading the view~

Comment: I just looked at your example view again. The script tag which had a src of attribute for jQuery was  containing your script, so you just needed to remove the src attribute. Maybe update your post with what it looks like now.

Comment: Indeed. With that the problem for that view is gone, although another problem showed up for another view but that would be another question. If you want to add an answer below so I can accept it feel free to do so.

Comment: Glad you got this part sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is a reference to jquery twice, once in your '_layout' and once in your view. Only one in the layout should be required.
2. I cannot see a boostrap.css or boostrap.min.css file. You have one for datatables, one for 'lumen', but not the primary bootstrap css file (i.e. https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css).
3. Looks like you have two bootstrap.js references too (once in layout and once near your navbar - again, only one should be required).

Comment: Calc, if you happen to feel like scratching your head with a similar problem (local version works ok but online version present a similar problem) I give you this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605329/asp-net-core-jquery-error-404-for-the-online-version-of-the-project  :)