# ASP.NET Core: jQuery Error 404 for the online version of the project

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, azure, asp.net-core-mvc

**The problem:**

Recently I've been modifying my Javascripts references in my project since they were repeting in several views (between the _Layout and views) causing errors.

At this moment there are no visible errors while working locally but once the project is online (thru Azure) the error 404: failed to load resource appears in the scripts section.

**Information:**

This is the current _Layout of the project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html" charset="utf-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Plataforma Fantasy Park</title>

    <environment names="Development">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        <script src="~/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap-lumen.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/nestednavbar.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
    </environment>

    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~js/jquery-3.2.1.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-K+ctZQ+LL8q6tP7I94W+qzQsfRV2a+AfHIi9k8z8l9ggpc8X+Ytst4yBo/hH+8Fk">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="/css/bootstrap-sand.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>





    @RenderSection("css", required: false)
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2017 - Plataforma Fantasy Park</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

As it can be seen, both the `Development` and `Staging,Production` enviroments have the references for jquery but for the purpose of this project I'll be working only with the references of the `Development` enviroment.

However, in the online version this errors show up:

[image]

I had these errors and it usually was because the jQuery was defined more than once in the view, or after a dependency such as bootstrap was declared, but this does not seem the case. As a **consecuence** none of the jQuery scripts is executing properly on the online version.

This is the result of the Network tab:

[image]

It looks like the jquery librery is being loaded correctly.

The following code is the source code of the view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html" charset="utf-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Index - Plataforma Fantasy Park</title>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js?v=qcV1wr-bn4NoBtxYqghmy1WIBvxeoe8vQlCowLG-cng"></script>
        <script src="/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js?v=X_58s5WblGMAw9SpDtqnV8dLRNCawsyGwNqnZD0Je_s"></script>
        <script src="/js/site.js?v=ViqmmChOp_51fH3dM_KEQAFClKU0vp0UrxlREwyHKHc"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-lumen.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/nestednavbar.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />    

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container body-content">


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Menu</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Plataforma Fantasy Park</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li><a href="/HechosLiquidadors/IndexAdmin">Liquidaciones</a></li>
                                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Máquinas <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" tabindex="-1">Registro</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="/Machines">Datos Comerciales</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="/Machines/Workshop">Datos de Fabricación</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="/Machines/Familias">Familias y Tipos</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" tabindex="-1">Gestión</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="/Machines/Management">Máquinas</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="/Machines/Contadores">Contadores</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Tiendas <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="/Stores">Registro</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="/Stores/Management">Liquidadores</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Proveedores <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="/Suppliers/Supplier">Fabricantes y Marcas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Suppliers/Dealer">Dealers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                                <li><a href="/">Gastos</a></li>
                                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Usuarios <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="/User">Usuarios</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/ApplicationRole">Roles</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
            </ul>


    <form method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right" action="/Account/SignOff">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a title="Manage" href="/Manage">Hello adelgado!</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Log off</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8P12Ot7bDOBImhnZFhlI8qHJtKdMI-7lr8LhbUsd_y-3eQSYnYA19_MyhKx_JGsHcwdpm_ZQCqHibSVsLLwXaJ-PRiZg6VJXvFUtHaAK6IAPSBfOgrVrEBeimgbOvB60ahTqLMUeuUsFEXIIrmYiyBgxQVeQJEkPBbIEsMlFv-8A91-ULjKZlim2P0NZaUuLSA" /></form>

            </div>
        </div>
</nav>




<h2>Tiendas</h2>

<div class="btn-group" id="modalbutton">
    <a id="createEditStoreModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-action-store" class="btn btn-primary" href="/Stores/Create">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>  Nueva Tienda
        </a>
</div>
<p></p>
<table id="stores" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Tienda
            </th>
            <th>
                Dirección
            </th>
            <th>
                Área
            </th>
            <th>
                Distrito
            </th>
            <th>
                Cadena
            </th>
            <th>Editar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>


<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="modal-action-store-label" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="modal-action-store" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog ">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2017 - Plataforma Fantasy Park</p>
        </footer>
    </div>


<script src="/js/store-index.js?v=xMseET7-q434oUXfBjpd5QKjSw8t0R0P_mGdZorHwB0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var global = this;
    var wasclicked = 0;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        document.getElementById("modalbutton").onclick = function () {
            global.wasclicked = 1;
        };

        $('#modal-action-store').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            global.wasclicked = 0;
        });

        $('#modal-action-store').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            if (global.wasclicked == 1) {
                var items = "<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Distrito --</option>";
                $('#DistrictID').html(items);
            }
            $('#DepartmentID').change(function () {
                var url = '/' + "Stores/GetDistrict";
                var ddlsource = "#DepartmentID";
                $.getJSON(url, { DepartmentID: $(ddlsource).val() }, function (data) {
                    var items = '';
                    $("#DistrictID").empty();
                    $.each(data, function (i, district) {
                        items += "<option value='" + district.value + "'>" + district.text + "</option>";
                    });
                    $('#DistrictID').html(items);
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I have been trying to detect what could be wrong for the online version to produce some errors that were not shown while the project was tested locally but I haven't succeeded in trying to find out. Hope anyone can help me understand what could be wrong in this case.

**Update:**

For what I tested, it seems like jQuery works for a few seconds and then suddenly stops working but no error message related to this is displayed.

Note to mention, the error message appears at the top of the html too:

[image]

But that can be related to the fact that is missing these files:

[image]

Comment: If you hit f12 in the browser and go to the network tab. Can you confirm the 404 on loading the jquery lib? Or post the url of the production version.

Comment: @JPHellemons Hello. I just added the screenshot for the result of the Network-tab. It's a project that requires username and password but if you need some other information let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Is this screenshot of the local version? or the production? Because jquery.min.js has a 200 (ok)

Comment: Production, and yes, that seems to be fine. I'm starting to wonder if the script contained in store-index.js is ok just because I don't know whereelse to look at

Comment: if it helps on anything, just to mention that the error message appears at the top of the html page too https://i.imgur.com/rL4OEIx.png

Comment: Maybe you need set `<configuration>  
  <system.webServer>    
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
        <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>` in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a boolean var?

instead of

```
var global = this;
var wasclicked = 0;
```

Something like thise:

```
var isClicked = false;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#modalbutton").on("click", function () {
        isClicked = true;
    });

    $('#modal-action-store').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        isClicked = false;
    });

    $('#modal-action-store').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        if (isClicked) {
            var items = "<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Distrito --</option>";
            $('#DistrictID').html(items);
        }
        $('#DepartmentID').change(function () {
            var url = '/' + "Stores/GetDistrict";
            var ddlsource = "#DepartmentID";
            $.getJSON(url, { DepartmentID: $(ddlsource).val() }, function (data) {
                var items = '';
                $("#DistrictID").empty();
                $.each(data, function (i, district) {
                    items += "<option value='" + district.value + "'>" + district.text + "</option>";
                });
                $('#DistrictID').html(items);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello JP. After some attemps I believe what is causing the jQuery to not work properly is that some part of the code could be improved and that this error is distracting us from other problem that I detail here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47611622/bootstrap-modal-load-data-into-the-modal-passing-href